# Debugging MySQL Deadlocks on Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, hibernate, amazon-web-services

I'm getting an increasing number of "Deadlock" and "Lock timeout" issues on my MySQL database (an Amazon RDS instance).  The database was working very well until a couple of days ago. No changes to the server code (that executes the queries) were made for more than a week. I know what the exceptions are, but I'm at a loss as to the best way to debug and find the specific queries/statements that are causing the issues.

Info on setup:

- MySQL Amazon RDS instance (small)
- Everything default in RDS profile/MySQL settings except for character encoding, which is changed to UTF-8
- Server making the queries is Tomcat Java server with Hibernate
- Information on exceptions is read from the Tomcat server log
- Queries / Min between 50 - 5000

My best guess is there's something in the settings (either Hibernate or MySQL) that's causing this issue. The server will run fine and then latency will go through the roof causing all sorts of negative behavior. When this happens, the CPU utilization of the instance will be near 100%.

The hibernate settings are:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass"><value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value></property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl"><value>XXXX</value></property>
    <property name="user"><value>XXXX</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>XXXX</value></property>
    <property name="initialPoolSize"><value>3</value></property>
    <property name="minPoolSize"><value>3</value></property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize"><value>50</value></property>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod"><value>200</value></property>
    <property name="acquireIncrement"><value>1</value></property>
    <property name="maxStatements"><value>0</value></property>
    <property name="numHelperThreads"><value>6</value></property>
</bean>
```

Any idea where to start debugging of if something in the settings might be causing this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Did u manage to find some answers ?

Comment: what's the output of command SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS?

Comment: you should have looked at the RDS error logs. the deadlocks are logged there

Answer (score 2):

I know it hard to locate the problem but you can start with locate the query that cause a deadlocks using:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

[MYSQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html)

Hope this will help you to start

Comment: unfortunately, it only shows the currently executing queries. RDS maintains an errors log that keeps some history

Comment: that's correct, you can view the log, and you can show the all the process to get start with the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use "show engine innodb status". It would usually give a lot of sections, but one section for deadlock is what would be of interest to you.